# Hold state of buttons dont work after binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have a UWP application where the buttons hold state work just fine until I bind (any) buttons visibility or editable state where the hold state goes away. The buttons only work if I tap super quickly after something gets binded. If I switch to a different view then back to the original view, the buttons magically work again. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Added the IsHoldingState="true" to parent and button in xaml.

xaml code

```
<controls:RoundedButton Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SubmitButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="{Binding IsNotEmpty, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}" Margin="-16,-16,-32,-32" Width="384" Height="112" Opacity="0" Background="Transparent" />


<controls:RoundedButton Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource SubmitButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="{Binding IsNotEmpty, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}">
```

cs code (where the binding is updated via onpropertychanged)

```
                      private bool isNotEmpty;
    public bool IsNotEmpty
    {
        get { return isNotEmpty; }
        set { Set(() => IsNotEmpty, ref isNotEmpty, value); }
    }

        protected bool Set<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression, ref T field, T value)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(selectorExpression);
        return true;
    }


        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression)
    {
        var propertyName = GetPropertyName(selectorExpression);
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }


  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I can't reproduce your question, can you provide the problem code, which helps me solve the problem. The other is that when you roll back the page, if you don't cache the page, the state of the page will be refreshed, which may be why your button works again.

Comment: Hi of course, added some more info that maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your `ConverterParameter`, `ConverterParameter` can't be directly assigned to a `boolean` value, please try this:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <x:Boolean x:Key="DefaultParameter">False</x:Boolean>
</Page.Resources>
...
<controls:RoundedButton Visibility="{Binding IsNotEmpty, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource DefaultParameter}}">
```

Best regards.